# python pyodbc: Closing the cursor before conn.commit()?

Tags: python, mysql, odbc, sql-insert, pyodbc

I have an issue with inserting data into a database using the python package pyodbc and since I am pretty new to pyodbc & databases in general, I might lack some basic understanding.

I open a connection, and then I want the execute my query.
Actually, in this query I call a stored procedure (which I didn't write and I am not allowed to change!).
This procedure does "one or two" inserts. When I use pyodbc like this

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
with conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("{call input_procedure('some','parameters','to','insert')}")
```

OR

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("{call input_procedure('some','parameters','to','insert')}")
conn.commit()
```

I get the following error message:
`pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now (2014) (SQLEndTran(SQL_COMMIT))")`

As far as I understood, this error message might be due to executing more than one insert within the called procedure.  When I print the return of the execute command I become the following: `(' ', )`

When I instead close the cursor, before doing the commit, everything works fine. Like this:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("{call input_procedure('some','parameters','to','insert')}")
c.close()
conn.commit()
```

I really don't understand what's happening here.
Is there an explanation for this behaviour? Is closing the cursor before doing the commit save?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Huh. Dunno what flavour of SQL your running or what the settings are, but here I can run c.execute() then c.commit() without problems when adding to a database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Yes, when doing a simple insert, everything works as expected. But it fails when I call the stored procedure...

Comment: Ah, can you even see into that procedure to see if its doing something exotic?

Comment: Hm, "exotic" could be, that with certain sets of parameters the function is called twice. Moreover, an "sRetval" is set. Don't know, whether this is common....

Comment: In your second example try calling `c.fetchall()` immediately after `c.execute( … )`

Comment: Thank you, @GordThompson . Unfortunately still the same error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have encountered a quirk in MySQL Connector/ODBC's handling of result sets from a stored procedure. For this example procedure:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `input_procedure`(IN `p1` VARCHAR(50))
   MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table1 (txt) VALUES (p1);
SELECT '' AS foo;
END
```

this Python code

```py
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("{call input_procedure('thing')}")
cnxn.commit()
```

throws the "Commands out of sync" error, whereas this code

```py
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("{call input_procedure('thing')}")
while crsr.nextset():
    pass
cnxn.commit()
```

does not.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, this does the job!